# HTML jQuery change paragraph text with image by a thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, image, replace, paragraph

I'm just started using jQuery in my site, which has a gallery like site with a bunch of thumbnails. When i click a thumbnail i want the picture to open in a new div box with the related text. I have managed to change the image in the div box, so it fits with it's thumbnail, but i can't seem to figure out how to change the text with it. It's a relativly long text beneath eath image, and i want each thumbnail to have a different text and image.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="showcontent">
    <h1 class="content_header">HEADER</h1>
    <img class="content_image" src="img/image_01_large.png" alt="" />
    <p class="text_01">
        texttexttext
    </p>
    <p class="text_02">
        text text text
    </p>
</div>
<div id="thumbnails">
    <p>
<img src="img/image_01_thumb.png" alt=""/>
<img src="img/image_02_thumb.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="img/image_03_thumb.png" alt=""/>
    <img src="img/image_04_thumb.png" alt=""/>
    </p>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
function viewContent(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#thumbnails img').click(function(){
            $('.content_image').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
            $('#showcontent p').attr('class').replace('.text_01', '.text_02');
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Where is the text_02 class your replacing it with?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure if I understand your question.

However I think you need to change the text inside "text_01" on clicking the images.

So you  need to have some text associated with the image, I will be using the alt attribute for the same.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbnails img').click(function(){
        $('.content_image').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
        $('#showcontent p').html($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinaylobo/KFM4w/3/